# "Dies unus"—non primus?

Tags: vulgata, numerals, grammar-choice

Genese 1:5 Hieronymus traduxit:

> Appellavitque lucem Diem, et tenebras Noctem: factumque est vespere et mane, dies **unus**.

Cur "unus", non "primus"? Nonne numerum ordinalem significat? Nonne "unus" est cardinalis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a literal translation of the Hebrew original, which has *yom ehad* "one day", not *yom rishon* "first day".

Comment: This is correct. On top of which, in English inverting the noun and modifier makes it clear what's going on. It's not 'one day,' but rather 'day one.'

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Wouldn't "day one" in English be equivalent to "the first day"?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I'm not sure that's actually true because the following days are given ordinals in the Hebrew: *yom sheni* "second day", etc. If the intended sense was "day one", you'd probably get cardinals across the board for "day two" etc.

Answer (score 11):

It's a cardinal number, not an ordinal number, in the original Hebrew. Look at [the other uses of the same Hebrew phrase](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/echad_259.htm):

[Genesis 1:9](http://biblehub.com/text/genesis/1-9.htm) ([NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%201:9)):

> And God said, “Let the water under the sky be gathered to **one** place, and let dry ground appear.” And it was so.

[Genesis 2:24](http://biblehub.com/text/genesis/2-24.htm) ([NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+2%3A24&version=NIV)):

> That is why a man leaves his father and mother and is united to his wife, and they become **one** flesh.

And so on. The vast majority are clearly 'one'.

The [NAS translates Gen 1:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+1%3A5&version=NASB) literally as "one day":

> God called the light day, and the darkness He called night. And there was evening and there was morning, **one day**.